# PHP > How to divide a Class into multiple Class?

Tags: php, class, object, constructor-chaining

I have a very big PHP class called "Player".

There is a lot of functions inside it(almost 2000 lines). Actually, I use those functions in this way :

```
$player = new Player(1)
echo $player->getLogin();
echo $player->getStatisticPerception();
echo $player->getWeaponId();
echo $player->attackPlayerId(3,$player->getWeaponId());
```

I think it could be a good idea to divide this class into multiples classes, but I don't know how. How could I create something like, for example :

```
$player = new Player(1);
echo $player->getLogin();
echo $player->statistics->getAttack();
echo $player->stuff->getWeaponId();
echo $player->doAction->attackPlayerId(3, $player->getWeaponId());
```

If think I have to create an object inside this object, but if I do so, i can't access the main "$player"'s object data (for example, in the Stuff Object, I can't access on the $level variable of the Player Object.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create multiple clases like `PlayerStatistics`, `Weapon` and `PlayerActions` and link them to the Player Class... an example:

```
class Player{
    private Statistics; 
    private Weapon;

    function __construct(){
        $this->Statistics = new Statistics($this);
        $this->Weapon = new Weapon($this);
    }

    function getAttack(){
        return $this->Statistics->getAttack();
    }
}

class Statistics{
    private Player;
    function __construct($_player){
         $this->Player = $_player;
    }
}
```

something like that... it's an [object composition or aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition), depending on the relation between objects.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use class inheritance

```
Class Player {
  protected $level;
  public $stuff;
  function __construct() {
    $this->stuff = new Stuff();
  }
}

Class Stuff extends Player {
  function getWeaponId() {
    // You can access Player's $level here using $this->level
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a line like this:

```
echo $player->statistics->getAttack();
```

You are accessing the `statistics` member of the Player class. In order to use chaining, that variable must also be an object. You can create a separate Statistics class that includes a `getAttack` method. Then in the Player class constructor, initialise `$this->statistics` to an instance of the Statistics class.

Similarly for `stuff` and `doAction`, they would need to be objects. Although I'm not sure they are really appropriate candidates for separate objects.